# ScrollView laggs too much on scrolling android

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

i am using scrollview in Linearlayout , the problem is layout respond normally, as soon as i start scrolling, it laggs too much.

```
< LinearLayout > 
< ScrollView >
< Linearlayout >..sub (LinearLayout)..< /LinearLayout >
< ScrollView>
< LinearLayout> 



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
    >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/pddd"
                >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_user_email_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Complete Your profile"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name   :"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/profileActivity_student_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mobile : "
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/profileActivity_student_mobile_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/profile_faculty_radio_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:text="Faculty"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/profile_parents_radio_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:text="Parents"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_faculty_key_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="6">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Key :"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pff_key"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/faculty_verify_bt_id"
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/check"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/faculty_cancle_bt_id"
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/minus1"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/proile_activity_unique_key_linearlayout_id"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Key :"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/profile_activity_school_key"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"


                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_activity_school_key_verify_bt_id"
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/check"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_activity_school_key_cancle_bt_id"
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/minus1"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                >


                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/activityprofile_spinner_id"
                    android:layout_width="200sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
                    >
                </Spinner>


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/profile_saveinfo_id"
                    android:layout_width="100sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/save2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/profile_nagivate_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Navigate" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

i have used this code for my Linearlayout, As soon as i touch radioButton or edittext or i scrolldown, It start lagging alot. Im not able to understand the problem, the images i have used are small size below 100kb

Comment: What resides inside your layout? Are you showing images? Post full xml

Comment: have you added any listeners to those layouts? Like onTouchListener?

Comment: here is my complete code that i have used.

Comment: You can try to check CPU usage in Android Profiler while scrolling down slowly. The point where cpu is going to peak gonna point your the next view going to be shown is the problem.

Comment: Try to use just one `RelativeLayout` inside the `ScrollView` instead of so many nested `LinearLayout`s.

Comment: The way im using Scrollview , is it Correct?

Comment: @ Emre Aktürk  As soon as application starts  it consume all the memory allocated to application(66MB) only 2MB of memory is left which is fluctuating. Something Wrong With it??

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code and took out about 4 `LinearLayout`s which were unnecessary. Please test it for performance. If it still is slow try substituting some of the remaining vertical `LinearLayout`s with `RelativeLayout`s as @IshitaShinha suggested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pddd"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_email_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Complete Your profile"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name   :"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/profileActivity_student_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mobile : "
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/profileActivity_student_mobile_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/profile_faculty_radio_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:text="Faculty"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/profile_parents_radio_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:text="Parents"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_faculty_key_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Key :"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pff_key"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/faculty_verify_bt_id"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/check"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/faculty_cancle_bt_id"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/minus1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/proile_activity_unique_key_linearlayout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Key :"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/profile_activity_school_key"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_activity_school_key_verify_bt_id"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/check"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_activity_school_key_cancle_bt_id"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/minus1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/activityprofile_spinner_id"
            android:layout_width="200sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profile_saveinfo_id"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/save2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profile_nagivate_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Navigate" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?